# C# MVC View to return City and State names instead of id's

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am having some issues trying to figure out how to display the names of the state and city instead of the StateId and CityId.

I am aware that you can put an instance of States and Cities in the model like this:

```
 public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }
 public virtual States States { get; set; }
```

And then add this to the view:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cities.CityName)
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.States.StateName)
```

However I have a few things that do not allow me to do this without error.
I use a ViewModel that gives me what I need for the view. It relies on a list from Addresses Table and in the Addresses Model I have Select Lists for these so that I can populate a dropdown list for each on edit and create.
When I add these to this to the Model and remove the selectLists I get an error that says it cannot find the Column Cities_CityId, States_StateId.
When I add it to the viewModel it just isn't available on the view. If I only needed it while showing 1 record I can use

```
Model.Cities.CityName
```

But I am retrieving several records, if they exist and using that would display the same city and state for all records, I believe..

I believe that all of my joins are correct but could be missing something.

Below is the ViewModel:

```
public partial class AddressOverview 
{
    public static AddressOverview GetAddressByCompany(int id, GeneralEntities db)
    {
        var qCus = from ad in db.Addresses
                   join cn in db.CompanyNames on ad.CompanyId equals cn.CompanyId
                   join cit in db.Cities on ad.City equals cit.CityId
                   join st in db.States on ad.State equals st.StateId
                   where (ad.CompanyId == id)
                   select new AddressOverview()
                   {
                       AddressId = ad.AddressId,
                       Customer = cn.CompanyName,
                       Location = ad.LocationName,
                       Addresses = ad,
                       CompanyId = ad.CompanyId,
                       State = st.StateName,
                       City = cit.CityName
                   };


        var result = qCus.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CompanyId == result.CompanyId);

        };
        return result;
    }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyNames CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual States States { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Addresses> AddressDetail { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        //Trying to get a view model for customer from the received UserId.
        AddressOverview modelInstance = AddressOverview.GetAddressByCompany(id, db);
        
        if (modelInstance == null)
        {
            //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            return RedirectToAction("/Add/", new { id });
        }
        return View(modelInstance);
    }
```

I am wondering if maybe there is a way to do this in the controller using the modelInstance? Please forgive me, I am trying to clean up some things that someone else did and my skills are a little weak.
If you need to see something else let me know.
Thanks for your help!

Update:
I just had a smack in the head moment.. Looking at View from question posted below I noticed that I was calling it from the Addresses Model instead of the ViewModel. So I corrected that but it still does not work..
Changed from this:

```
@model MyProject.GenerDTO.Entities.Addresses
```

To:

```
@model MyProject.Models.AddressOverview
```

Update:
Here is the solution I came up with. Probably not the best, but certainly a quick fix..

I decided to create a view on the MSSQL side and bring all of this together and then used that in the view and the ViewModel. If you decide to do something like this. Be sure to make sure that it is [NotMapped] in the entities. We are only using this to view and it is not meant to be used for editing, creating, etc.

Here is the new View Model:

```
public partial class AddressOverview 
{
    public static AddressOverview GetAddressByCompany(int id, GeneralEntities db)
    {
        var qCus = from ad in db.AddressView
                   join cn in db.CompanyNames on ad.CompanyId equals cn.CompanyId
                   where (ad.CompanyId == id)
                   select new AddressOverview()
                   {
                       AddressId = ad.AddressId,
                       Customer = cn.CompanyName,
                       Location = ad.LocationName,
                       AddressView = ad,
                       CompanyId = ad.CompanyId
                       
                   };


        var result = qCus.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.AddressDetail = db.AddressView.Where(a => a.CompanyId == result.CompanyId);
        };
        return result;
    }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressView AddressView { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyNames CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<AddressView> AddressDetail { get; set; }
}
```

I believe that creating a view in SQL is clean and the query is done server side. It can be treated like a table in the project. I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Could you show the first lines of the view that should receive your model?

Comment: I see you are not populating the cities and states in the static method so if you are using those in your view you going to have an issue

Comment: @Jed Yes I explained that. I need to have it use the id in the addresses table and populate the corresponding Name froml the City Table in the foreach..